# In Google Spreadsheet, finding what formulas reference a given value

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I would like to find out which cells have formula dependencies in a large spreadsheet. I am looking for a way to do something like OpenOffice

> Tools>Detective>Trace dependents

and

> Edit>Find & Replace>Search in formulas

or a way to create a trigger in GAS that gets called when a given cell value is referenced and can identify the source of the reference.

Answer (score 12):

The following code will add a menu to the Spreadsheet:

Detective > Trace Dependents

Selecting this will add a note to the active cell with all dependent cell references.

(added search for static references as suggested by Graham below)

You could add a similar function to the traceDependents function to search for the text within the active cell for a Search in Formulas function. I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = []
  menuEntries.push({name: "Trace Dependents", functionName: "traceDependents"});
  ss.addMenu("Detective", menuEntries);
}

function traceDependents(){
  var dependents = []
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var currentCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  var currentCellRef = currentCell.getA1Notation();
  var range = ss.getDataRange();

  var regex = new RegExp("\\b" + currentCellRef + "\\b");
  var formulas = range.getFormulas();

  for (var i = 0; i < formulas.length; i++){
    var row = formulas[i];

    for (var j = 0; j < row.length; j++){
      var cellFormula = row[j].replace(/\$/g, "");
      if (regex.test(cellFormula)){
        dependents.push([i,j]);
      }
    }
  }

  var dependentRefs = [];
  for (var k = 0; k < dependents.length; k ++){
    var rowNum = dependents[k][0] + 1;
    var colNum = dependents[k][1] + 1;
    var cell = range.getCell(rowNum, colNum);
    var cellRef = cell.getA1Notation();
    dependentRefs.push(cellRef);
  }
  var output = "Dependents: ";
  if(dependentRefs.length > 0){
    output += dependentRefs.join(", ");
  } else {
    output += " None";
  }
  currentCell.setNote(output);
}
```

Comment: I like this very much! Do I see it correctly that it doesn't support Named Ranges, though? And if that is the case, would it be simple/complicated to add support?

Comment: Nearly Perfect (even though I seem to be late to the party)! Unfortunately it will not find "fixed Cells". E.g.: `=1+A$1` will not be found but `=1+A1` will be found. Any ideas?

Comment: How to use the code?

Comment: Where do you put this code?

Comment: @Sam You need to edit the Google Apps Script section - a quick google search should help you find it.

Comment: TomHorwood, Thanks! I'm an embedded programmer so all this newfangled online scripting is scary and confusing to me. I think you answered @Ferrybig question too

Comment: why does the line `menuEntries.push({name: "Trace Dependents", functionName: "traceDependents"});` appear twice in the code?

Comment: This is great but doesn't find references that are within a referenced range. For example, in cell `A5` the code will not find cell with formula `=sum(A1:A10)` as a will not be dependent.

Comment: How can this be modified to trace dependents on a named range.  (If this comment interests you, you could do it as a question and self answer.)

Comment: So frustrating. This looks like it does exactly what I need, but I can't get it to work. Tried "Tools > Script Editor" from within the spreadsheet, then saving, running, giving permissions ... but I don't see "Trace Dependents" anywhere. Any chance for some basic instructions on how to install it?

Answer (score 4):

This is super and has saved me much work - thanks.
However the answer above does not find any references that use the row- or column-fixer `$`.
The following slight change to code accomplishes that:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = []
  menuEntries.push({name: "Trace Dependents", functionName: "traceDependents"});
  ss.addMenu("Detective", menuEntries);
}

function traceDependents(){
  var dependents = []
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var currentCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  var currentCellRef = currentCell.getA1Notation();
  var range = ss.getDataRange();

  var regex = new RegExp("\\b" + currentCellRef + "\\b");
  var formulas = range.getFormulas();

  for (var i = 0; i < formulas.length; i++){
    var row = formulas[i];

    for (var j = 0; j < row.length; j++){
      var cellFormula = row[j].replace(/\$/g, "");
        if (regex.test(cellFormula)){
          dependents.push([i,j]);
      }
    }
  }

  var dependentRefs = [];
  for (var k = 0; k < dependents.length; k ++){
    var rowNum = dependents[k][0] + 1;
    var colNum = dependents[k][1] + 1;
    var cell = range.getCell(rowNum, colNum);
    var cellRef = cell.getA1Notation();
    dependentRefs.push(cellRef);
  }
  var output = "Dependents: ";
  if(dependentRefs.length > 0){
    output += dependentRefs.join(", ");
  } else {
    output += " None";
  }
  currentCell.setNote(output);
}
```

Comment: Thanks; this helped somewhat. How would one make it work across worksheets?

Comment: Thanks Graham - I've incorporated your changes. As to working across worksheets, the code would need a bit of adjusting to incorporate the sheet name and then loop through each of the sheets