# How can I trace precedents in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

In Excel we can trace precedents and dependents. Can some one help me with something similar for Google Sheets?

I have got the code for dependents from https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/50149/88163.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = []
  menuEntries.push({name: "Trace Dependents", functionName: "traceDependents"});
  ss.addMenu("Detective", menuEntries);
}

function traceDependents(){
  var dependents = []
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var currentCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  var currentCellRef = currentCell.getA1Notation();;
  var range = ss.getDataRange();

  var regex = new RegExp("\\b" + currentCellRef + "\\b")
  var formulas = range.getFormulas();

  for (var i = 0; i < formulas.length; i++){
    var row = formulas[i];

    for (var j = 0; j < row.length; j++){
      var cellFormula = row[j];
      if (regex.test(cellFormula)){
        dependents.push([i,j]);
      }
    }
  }

  var dependentRefs = [];
  for (var k = 0; k < dependents.length; k ++){
    var rowNum = dependents[k][0] + 1;
    var colNum = dependents[k][1] + 1;
    var cell = range.getCell(rowNum, colNum);
    var cellRef = cell.getA1Notation();
    dependentRefs.push(cellRef);
  }
  var output = "Dependents: ";
  if(dependentRefs.length > 0){
    output += dependentRefs.join(", ");
  } else {
    output += " None";
  }
  currentCell.setNote(output);
}
```

Comment: Also note this works for formulae in one sheet - can we make it work for other sheets in same file

Comment: Question title is about precedents, but all discussion is about dependents. What gives. No solution for precedents?

Answer (score 3):

Worked with the above (works with all sheets), but made the following changes:

1. Can handle absolute references
2. Now prints to a draggable prompt so it doesn't write over notes
3. Handles variability in sheet names (besides "Sheet1" Sheet2" etc)

--

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = []
  menuEntries.push({name: "Trace Dependents", functionName: "traceDependents"});
  ss.addMenu("Trace Dependents", menuEntries);
}

function traceDependents(){
  var dependentRefs = [];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var currentCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  var currentCellRef = currentCell.getA1Notation();;

  var cellRightLength = currentCell.getRow().toString().length
  var cellLength = currentCell.getA1Notation().length
  var columnText = currentCell.getA1Notation().substring(0,cellLength-cellRightLength)
  var rowText = currentCell.getRow().toString()


  Logger.log(currentCellRef);
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var actSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var actSheetGetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var actIndex = actSheet.getIndex();

  //Need to search and see if there is a space in the sheet name.  If there   is, in other cells in other sheets it will be surronded by: ' 
  //Otherwise, it won't have   '   characters around it

  spaceRegex = new RegExp(" ")
  if (spaceRegex.test(actSheetGetName) == true) {
     actSheetName = "'" + actSheetGetName + "'" + "!"
  } else {
     actSheetName = actSheetGetName + "!"
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++){
    var range = sheets[i].getDataRange();
    var currentSheetRef;
    if (i == actIndex - 1){
      currentSheetRef='';
    } else {
      currentSheetRef = actSheetName
    }
    Logger.log(currentSheetRef + currentCellRef);

    var regex1 = new RegExp(currentSheetRef + currentCellRef)
    var regex2 = new RegExp(currentSheetRef + "\\$" + currentCellRef)
    var regex3 = new RegExp(currentSheetRef + columnText + "\\$" + rowText)
    var regex4 = new RegExp(currentSheetRef + "\\$" + columnText + "\\$" + rowText)

    var formulas = range.getFormulas();
    var dependents = [];
    Logger.log("Range");
    Logger.log(range.getA1Notation());
    Logger.log(formulas);
    for (var j = 0; j < formulas.length; j++){
      var row = formulas[j];

      for (var k = 0; k < row.length; k++){
        var cellFormula = row[k];
        if ((regex1.test(cellFormula)) || (regex2.test(cellFormula)) || (regex3.test(cellFormula)) || (regex4.test(cellFormula))) {
          dependents.push([j,k]);
        }
      }
    }
    Logger.log("Dependents");
    Logger.log(dependents);
    for (var l = 0; l < dependents.length; l++){
      var rowNum = dependents[l][0] + 1;
      var colNum = dependents[l][1] + 1;
      Logger.log(rowNum+' '+colNum);
      Logger.log(range.getA1Notation());
      var cell = range.getCell(rowNum, colNum);
      var cellRef = cell.getA1Notation();
      var sheetRef = sheets[i].getName()
      dependentRefs.push(sheetRef + "!" + cellRef);
    }
  }

  var output = "";
  if(dependentRefs.length > 0){
    output += dependentRefs.join("\n");
  } else {
    output += " None";
  }

  ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()   
  ui.alert('Dependents:',output,ui.ButtonSet.OK);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally I have it working for different sheets in the same file:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = []
  menuEntries.push({name: "Trace Dependents", functionName: "traceDependents"});
  ss.addMenu("Detective", menuEntries);
}

function traceDependents(){
  var dependentRefs = [];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var currentCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  var currentCellRef = currentCell.getA1Notation();;
  Logger.log(currentCellRef);
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var actSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var actIndex = actSheet.getIndex();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++){
    var range = sheets[i].getDataRange();
    var currentSheetRef;
    if (i == actIndex - 1){
      currentSheetRef='';
    } else {
      currentSheetRef = 'Sheet' + actIndex + '!';
    }
    Logger.log(currentSheetRef + currentCellRef);
    var regex = new RegExp("\\b" + currentSheetRef + currentCellRef + "\\b")
    var formulas = range.getFormulas();
    var dependents = [];
    Logger.log("Range");
    Logger.log(range.getA1Notation());
    Logger.log(formulas);
    for (var j = 0; j < formulas.length; j++){
      var row = formulas[j];

      for (var k = 0; k < row.length; k++){
        var cellFormula = row[k];
        if (regex.test(cellFormula)){
          dependents.push([j,k]);
        }
      }
    }
    Logger.log("Dependents");
    Logger.log(dependents);
    for (var l = 0; l < dependents.length; l++){
      var rowNum = dependents[l][0] + 1;
      var colNum = dependents[l][1] + 1;
      Logger.log(rowNum+' '+colNum);
      Logger.log(range.getA1Notation());
      var cell = range.getCell(rowNum, colNum);
      var cellRef = cell.getA1Notation();
      var sheetRef = 'Sheet' + (i+1) + '!';
      dependentRefs.push(sheetRef + cellRef);
    }
  }

  var output = "Dependents: ";
  if(dependentRefs.length > 0){
    output += dependentRefs.join(", ");
  } else {
    output += " None";
  }
  currentCell.setNote(output);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is an add-on for this now, you can install "Find Precedents and Dependents" from the add-ons menu in Google Sheets.

[image: find precedents and dependents google sheets add-on]

Comment: This is not available in the G Suite Marketplace (it's the new house for Google Sheets add-ons)