# Test if value of cell is used in a formula

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function

In a google sheet I have some values that are used in formulas in other cells (until now, nothing unusual...).

I would like these cells to have a special color to be aware that if I modifiy them, other cells will be modified as well. Is there a function to test if a cell's value is used elsewhere?

I am looking for a simple built-in way to do this, without macros, and I just need to know wether the cell is used elsewhere or not, not by whom, or neither what it does.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Related: [How can I trace precedents in Google Sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/77940/88163)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time there is no built-in way to find precedent/dependent cells, the only way is by using an add-on or script.

Related

- [In Google Spreadsheet, finding what formulas reference a given value](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/47817/88163)
- [How can I trace precedents in Google Sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/77940/88163)